# backbone.js set in model initialize not effecting models in collection

Tags: backbone.js

While performing a fetch() on my backbone collection, and instantiating models as children of that collection, I want to add one more piece of information to each model.

I thought that I could do this using `set` in the model initialize. (My assumption is that fetch() is instantiating a new model for each object passed into it. And therefore as each initialize occurs the extra piece of data would be set.

To illustrate my problem I've pasted in four snippets, first from my collection class. Second the initialize function in my model class. Third, two functions that I use in the initialize function to get the needed information from the flickr api. Fourth, and finally, the app.js which performs the `fetch()`.

First the collection class:

```
var ArmorApp = ArmorApp || {};
ArmorApp.ArmorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ArmorApp.singleArmor,
    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1SjHIBLTFb1XrlrpHxZ4SLE9lEJf4NyDVnKnbVejlL4w/1/public/values?alt=json",
  //comparator: "Century",
  parse: function(data){
    var armorarray = [];
    var entryarray = data.feed.entry;
    for (var x in entryarray){
        armorarray.push({"id": entryarray[x].gsx$id.$t,
                          "Filename": entryarray[x].gsx$filename.$t, 
                          "Century": entryarray[x].gsx$century.$t,
                          "Date": entryarray[x].gsx$date.$t,
                          "Country": entryarray[x].gsx$country.$t,
                          "City": entryarray[x].gsx$city.$t,
                          "Type": entryarray[x].gsx$type.$t,
                          "Maker": entryarray[x].gsx$maker.$t,
                          "Recepient": entryarray[x].gsx$recipient.$t,
                          "Flickrid": entryarray[x].gsx$flickrid.$t,
                          "FlickrUrl": "", //entryarray[x].gsx$flickrurl.$t,
                          "FlickrUrlBig": ""//entryarray[x].gsx$flickrurlbig.$t,
                        });
      }
      return armorarray;
  }
});
```

Second, the initialization in my model.

```
initialize: function(){
        //console.log("A model instance named " + this.get("Filename"));
        item = this;
        var flickrapi = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getSizes&api_key=<my_apikey>&photo_id=" + this.get("Flickrid") + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?"; 
        sources = getFlickrSources(flickrapi);
        sources.then(function(data){
            sourceArray = parseFlickrResponse(data);
            FlickrSmall = sourceArray[0].FlickrSmall;
            console.log (FlickrSmall);

            item.set("FlickrUrl", FlickrSmall);
            console.log(item);
        });
```

Notice here how I'm getting the "Flickrid" and using to get one more piece of information and then trying to add it back into the model with `item.set("FlickrUrl", FlickerSmall);`

`console.log` confirms that the property "FlickrUrl" has been set to the desired value.

Third, these are the functions my model uses to get the information it needs for the flicker api.

```
var getFlickrSources = function(flickrapi){
  flickrResponse = $.ajax({
      url: flickrapi,
      // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
      jsonp: "callback",
      // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
      dataType: "jsonp"})

  return flickrResponse;
}

var parseFlickrResponse = function(data){
  flickrSourceArray = []

  if (data.stat == "ok"){
    sizeArray = data.sizes.size;
    for (var y in sizeArray){
      if (sizeArray[y].label == "Small"){
        flickrSourceArray.push({"FlickrSmall": sizeArray[y].source});
      }
      else if (sizeArray[y].label == "Large"){
        flickrSourceArray.push({"FlickrLarge": sizeArray[y].source});
      }
    }
  }

  return flickrSourceArray
}
```

But, fourth, when I try to perform the fetch and render the collection, I only get objects in my collection without the `FlickrUrl` property set.

```
//create an array of models and then pass them in collection creation method
var armorGroup = new ArmorApp.ArmorCollection();

armorGroup.fetch().then(function(){
  console.log(armorGroup.toJSON());
  var armorGroupView = new ArmorApp.allArmorView({collection: armorGroup});
  $("#allArmor").html(armorGroupView.render().el);
});

var armorRouter = new ArmorApp.Router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

The `console.log` in this last snippet prints out all the objects/models supposedly instantiated through the fetch. But none of them include the extra property that should have been `set` during the initialization.

Any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What is this function ?  getFlickrSources(flickrapi)

Why are you using this.get in the initialize function. Honestly it looks over-complicated for what you are trying to do.

**If you want to set some parameter when you instantiate your model then do this** var model = new Model({ param:"someparam", url:"someurl",wtv:"somewtv"});

If the point is to update your model just write an update function in your model something like *update: function (newparam) { this.set;... etc* and call it when you need it.

If I read you well you just want to set some params when your model is instantiated, so just use what I specified above. Here is some more doc : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor

I hope it helps.

**edit:**

Put your call outside your model, you shouldn't (imo) make call inside your model this way it seems kinda dirty.

```
Sources.then(function(flickrdata) {
    var mymodel = new Model({flicker:flickrdata.wtv});
});
```

It would be cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: hmm, I don't doubt its over complicated. But I think I basically am doing the `this.set` approach you described. But before I set the property FlickerSmall i have to request the url of the desired image from the flicker API. That why i have to set the the property inside the `then()' function. I have to set the property after the request completes. I have added the `getFlickerSources` to my original post. I really appreciate your thoughts. I know its a complicated (perhaps convoluted) question.

Comment: don't use this.set in your init and don't call your stuff inside the init.

Make your api call outside mycall.then(fucntion() { new Model({FlickerSmall:... }

See what I mean ?